# How to apply filtering/paging to a list of entities before they are converted to viewmodels so we avoid materializing the entire list in memory?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am creating a WebAPI for use by mobile applications as well as our ASP.NET MVC4 webapp.  We are working with a huge database, so we need to avoid materializing lists of entities whenever possible.  Our WebAPI returns JSON.

The situation is simple...  A request for a list of licenses is received, but it must be paged because there are 500,000 records that could be returned.  How can I apply paging/filtering to the IQueryable list of entities before I convert them to a list of viewmodels that is returned?

Here is some test code that I am working with...

```
    // Get the list of licenses, but page them.
    // GET api/<controller>
    //[Queryable] 
    public IQueryable<LicenseViewModel> Get()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<LicenseEntity, LicenseViewModel>();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        List<LicenseViewModel> vms = new List<LicenseViewModel>();
        using (var repo = new LicenseRepository())
        {
            // Get the IQueryable<LicenseEntity> list...
            // IS THERE SOME WAY TO APPY PAGING/FILTERING HERE?
            var entities = repo.List();

            // Convert them to viewmodels.  ARGGG! This will materialize the huge list
            // if we cannot applyfiltering/paging in the previous step.
            foreach (var item in entities)
            {
                var vm = Mapper.Map<LicenseEntity, LicenseViewModel>(item);
                list.Add(vm);
            }
        }

        return vms.AsQueryable();
    }
```

I tried the following, but am receiving a "Children could not be evauluated" error when I tried to expand the list and see the results.

```
            using (var repo = new LicenseRepository())
            {
                // Get the list of entities...
                var list = repo
                    .List()
                    .Select(x => Mapper.Map(x, new LicenseViewModel()));

                return list;
            }
```

Thank you for your time and your suggestions,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this maps to the Web API but the principals are the same.

With WCF Dataservices which is essentially the same but I believe currently has a few extra features you can set the page size as below:

```
 public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
 {
        config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 20);
 }
```

Where the "*" is insert your entity set name.

By setting this, the feed will contain a continuation token which the client can use to request the next page.

In your repository you may need to handle the Take and Skip functions manually depending on your data source.

If the URL contains ?$top=10&$skip=0 then you can add this to your request from your datasource, see example below.

```
using (var repo = new LicenseRepository())
{
     // Get the list of entities...
     var list = repo                        
     .Select(x => Mapper.Map(x, new LicenseViewModel()))
     .Skip(0)
     .Take(10);
     return list;
}
```

Obviously change the skip/take values depending on what is in the $top and $skip elements of the URL.

Comment: Hi SCB, I discovered that an exception was being thrown, which resulted in the error that I mentioned.  Once I fixed it, my second set of code, which uses projection, worked.  Since I am returning an IQueryable from WebAPI, OData's filtering would work properly without having to add the Skip and Take items that you've mentioned.

Comment: Good to hear. You should post how you resolved your problem and mark it as the answer. Might help someone else

Comment: // Get an IQueryable list of LicenseEntity objects.
var entityList = LicenseRepository.List(adapter);

// Transform the list into an IQueryable list of 
// LicenseViewModel objects.
var vmList = entityList.Select(x => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(x, new LicenseViewModel()));

Comment: Unfortunately, I discovered a related issue with the .Select and it is being discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638659/linq-projection-is-not-including-all-data-from-the-original-entity

Answer (score 0):

For paging, you can use the ResultLimit feature that we added recently. You can say,

```
[Queryable(ResultLimit=10)]
```

to return only 10 items at a time.

And, the coolest part of this is we calculate the next page link as well. Next page link is the link that the client should follow to get the next page. If you are using the ODataFormatter the next page link is included in the response by default.  If you are using a different formatter we just calculate the link but don't put it into the response body as we don't know its format. you can write a message handler or an action filter to retrieve the link from

```
Request.Properties['MS_NextPageLink']
```

and write it to response body or response headers or wherever your client expects it to be.

Answer (score 0):

// Get an IQueryable list of LicenseEntity objects.
var entityList = LicenseRepository.List(adapter);

// Transform the list into an IQueryable list of 
// LicenseViewModel objects.
var vmList = entityList.Select(x => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(x, new LicenseViewModel()));

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for projecting domain entities to viewmodels.  If you are struggling with the same kind of issue as I had, please review the following links:

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/02/09/autoprojecting-linq-queries/
http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code

By the way, in one one my domain entities, I had a partial class with some "calculated" properties...  Properties whose values were generated from other fields in the database record.  These cannot be in the domain entity because they will interfere with the aforementioned solutions.  I moved them to my ViewModel class, which is where they were really required, and all is well.

Hope that this info helps...

Mike